# How to handle a post request in json format to own laptop in python via django or flask

Tags: python, flask

I have configured an http webhook on thethingsstack webpage cloud.thethings.network that performs a post request to a configured endpoint (my laptop) as follows:

```
http://xxx.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80
For uplink message: http://localhost:80/uplink-message
For join ack: http://localhost:80/join-accept
```

Using `ngrok.exe http 80` I can also see that I receive the post requests in my command line:

```
POST /uplink-enabled           502 Bad Gateway                                                                          POST /uplink-enabled           502 Bad Gateway                                                                          POST /uplink-enabled           502 Bad Gateway
```

However, I'm not able to receive the data in json format following the online tutorials:
[enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/)
[enter link description here](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/)
Is there a code example that listens continuously to the http port and handles post requests?

EDIT:
My flask code looks as follows:

```
# import main Flask class and request object
from flask import Flask, request

# create the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/uplink-enabled')
def query_example():
    return 'Query String Example'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run app in debug mode on port 5000
    app.run(debug=True, port=80)
```

I am also able to see incoming post requests but receive an error:

> - Debug mode: on  * Restarting with stat  * Debugger is active!  *
>   Debugger PIN: 852-174-427  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80/ (Press
>   CTRL+C to quit)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2021 11:12:46] "POST /uplink-enabled HTTP/1.1" 405 -

my ngrok interface looks as follows:

> Session Status                online
> Session Expires               1 hour, 19 minutes
> Version                       2.3.40
> Region                        United States (us)
> Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
> Forwarding                    http://xxx.ngrok.io ->
> http://localhost:80                                       Forwarding
> https://xxx.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80

Comment: post the flask app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route('/uplink-enabled', methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def query_example():
    return 'Query String Example'
```

This will handle 405 error.

Answer (score 0):

Your dev-server returns HTTP 405 (Method not allowed), because
route definition must explicitly define the method:

```py
@app.route('/uplink-enabled', methods=['POST'])
```